# DJANGO - The HTTP GET Request return nothing

Tags: python, django, http, get, request

I was running a python script that returned URLs of google search about a topic and it worked
so I tried to embed this script in Django to display these URLs on a webpage but it doesn't work anymore and does not display any error Where did I go wrong?

**urls.py in AppWEB**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.scrap, name='scrap')

]
```

**view.py in AppWeb**

```
def fetch( query):

     params = {
        'q': query,
        'sxsrf': 'ALiCzsbh0YEbk_cEHlMBgzgq_tPEfVLYiQ:1660146922900',
        'ei': '6tTzYrPNNsWM9u8PyLOOuAc',
        'ved': '0ahUKEwiz6vSc0bz5AhVFhv0HHciZA3cQ4dUDCA0',
        'tbs': 'qdr:d',
        'gs_lcp': 'Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyCAguEIAEENQCMgUILhCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCC4QgAQyCAguEIAEENQCMgsILhCABBDHARCvATIFCAAQgAQ6BAgAEEM6DgguEIAEEMcBENEDENQCOgsILhCABBDHARDRAzoFCAAQkQI6BwgjEOoCECc6BwguENQCEEM6BAguEENKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFjWFmCDGWgCcAF4AoABkweIAfQekgELMi00LjIuMC4xLjKYAQCgAQGwAQrAAQE'

    }
     headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'cookie': 'OTZ=6594569_52_56_174240_52_315300; SID=Mwgr1yh_8pdqxcCW4bAmUDoP5GOeVkusbuzcWHdOYXlNadWmdbOUtPITFz1UUQ3OM8vseA.; __Secure-1PSID=Mwgr1yh_8pdqxcCW4bAmUDoP5GOeVkusbuzcWHdOYXlNadWmRmqrl9iD_9UOIZNkvbqX-Q.; __Secure-3PSID=Mwgr1yh_8pdqxcCW4bAmUDoP5GOeVkusbuzcWHdOYXlNadWm-ywqR6vV-7MXRA_OAoLNSQ.; HSID=APDjrCSjYxzBvkMxC; SSID=AsSz-gQXwFFeJqQzw; APISID=5Qwkn_cNhMDuRqpZ/AYczojbKYldQo2t5b; SAPISID=wxHQFonmSjj6gGfI/A6yfUPmtjo4OFWvWX; __Secure-1PAPISID=wxHQFonmSjj6gGfI/A6yfUPmtjo4OFWvWX; __Secure-3PAPISID=wxHQFonmSjj6gGfI/A6yfUPmtjo4OFWvWX; OGPC=19022622-1:; SEARCH_SAMESITE=CgQIjpYB; AEC=AakniGMUfMDPvK8aZ7e5s1miz5lAntjOEygTd68cx9N_z5Fn3uDUsuzpZvs; 1P_JAR=2022-08-12-11; NID=511=tk_V5K8omiV0ceKov6QEdmx7ZHv09DNibXnysZs-9qSzgrEd0Q2PhMZVvo4OLQNzxU7NEruKDmY-DIAvlXwIooK6EPJ2dFHgSc_gb3ukJxpdYSyf6cUl30ZMJb_p-9whuvDcv-EUGed7mD7e1Vn4BzICgaDnrL1gw3PGPA78T188TXjPfPQg-DULaqdIOiwxgEsFD2zz5SbHuW0G9bm5dOq2n22Hw4d2lVGSA6w9nBzpLaeMHQUObSp_Aua2CKm1WqKdwH4Isjd84aNc1cMdEGYeqcIScj32M0xBvThOCynpQutIyszjHl0NaN9js0m06wrM51XHJ-EXidLPoVCqRE88txdEmKDJ8qcSREpYbuddzCMBKIg7u1NEpAm81nih; SIDCC=AEf-XMRyfzEKl27JhtXmvgFbTAk1-0YKLGcy9fOOR6lPAULVKhiY3ZfPQVTib3S3S1BmrDf1O0U; __Secure-1PSIDCC=AEf-XMTBmMvKCbMLFwPKBRDd3u1rlbKfgVxzVV1SQZFKucrNE9q-FEczUfVA1miYsfyX_0ypDJk; __Secure-3PSIDCC=AEf-XMSO1Xh3vQg15LldTb_mzifg8hacgWmM70oDPo8lo-jutQ7Ho9dEoeegIgEW6Yr2iaAsGuoz; DV=o66_OU3929pTIBy4P1MyROsAdBYeKRhfk61DJytXfAAAAAAifm2YC1-efQAAAHh0x-PxVD2eJgAAAGy871Dv-DMjFQAAAA',
        'referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36 OPR/89.0.4447.83'
    }
     base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search'
     params['q'] = query

        # Make HTTP GET request
     return requests.get(base_url, params=params, headers=headers)

def scrap(request):
    
        response = fetch('Parti Authenticité et Modernité(pam)')
        context = {
                'url': response.url,
                'code': response.status_code,
            }
        return render(request, 'index1.html',context)
```

**index1.html**

```
<p>Google search URL is : {{context.url}}</p>
<p> status of code is : {{context.code}}</p>
```

I got as a result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html:

```
<p>Google search URL is : {{ url }}</p>
<p> status of code is : {{ code }}</p>
```